# node.js Error generating response. TypeError: response.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node app, I'm trying to return a simple object and getting this error in my console:

> Error generating response. TypeError: response.json is not a function

code in my `messaging.js` file :

```
module.exports = {
    getConfig: function(res) {
        getConfig(res);
    }
};

function getConfig(response) {    
    response.json({
      enabledForAll: false,
      limit: 100
    });
};
```

In `main.js`

```
const messaging = require("./modules/messaging.js");
Parse.Cloud.define("getConfig", messaging.getConfig);
```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Are you using `express`?

Comment: Clearly the `response` object doesn't have a method called `json`. As to why who knows? What is `response`? Where is this being used? Are there any dependencies or is this pure node.js? There's not enough information to go on here.

Comment: I'm not importing it into my module currently, no

Comment: You should show more code, like how you are calling `getConfig` ...

Comment: I'm calling it in a PFCloud Parse function from my mobile client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parse [FunctionResponse](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v2.0.2/Parse.Cloud.html#.FunctionResponse) only has two properties. `success` and `error`.

Additionally, the `data` portion of the `define` callback has two function inputs, `FunctionRequest` and `FunctionResponse`, so you may need something like `function(req,res){ res.success();}`

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking around for. Appreciated Cody. Thanks